# How to insert a new element after each element in an array?

Tags: c, arrays

How to insert a new element after each element in an array?

For example I have an array `3,4,5,6,7` and I want to add `0` for example after each element. So after modifying the new array should be `3,0,4,0,5,0,6,0,7,0`

I've been trying to do this for the past few hours without any success.

Thank you all

Comment: What have you tried? It will be easier to help if we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: *I've been trying to do this for the past few hours without any success.* Please post what you have tried.

Comment: You can do this in-place if: (1) your array is large enough; and (2) you work backwards from the end of the array

Comment: I tried following: adding 0 in every non pair position (if array starts from 0,1,2,3...) then attempted moving each element to the next position, wasn't successful there, then I tried combining two arrays, original one and array of zeros into a new array than arranging it to make a desired array

Comment: Anyone who answers this question with code is denying the OP an opportunity to learn.

Comment: @paddy i use stack overflow as a last hope. I am always for learning alone unless I really dont know something

Comment: Next time you have difficulty with your code, post actual code of what you have tried and describe the undesirable behaviour you're trying to understand.  You will get better answers, and fewer down-votes.

Comment: I would post the code if I saved every thing I wrote :/ Every bit of code I wrote I knew what it was doing and where it went wrong. I ran out of ideas and came here. Did not learn anything here now apart from your idea. It's okay, if I come up with a solution I will post it here. And those who down-vote without explaining why are a bit rude, especially to an amateur. Anyway I've noticed that most of the community is quite unkind to beginners.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it should work.
If you're doing it in place, then you need to work backwards like this, otherwise you'll overwrite some of your array before you even read it.

```
//Make sure it has space for the zeros.
//If we have 5 numbers here, we need space for 10
int arr[10] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

//Start at the last number (index 4) and work your way down.
//If you start at zero and increment up, you will overwrite data at the beginning of the array.
for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
{
    arr[i * 2] = arr[i]; //Move the number
    arr[i * 2 + 1] = 0; //Add a zero after it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged it under C. I will avoid vector here.
Assuming you already have array of 10 integers already allocated either on stack on heap. Since you have 5 elements, you need 5 zeros. So total elements in resultant array will be 10.

```
void function(int arr[], int size)
{
    int loc = size/2;
    while(size>=0)
    {
        if(size&1)
            arr[size--] = arr[loc--];
        else
            arr[size--] = 0;
    }
}
```